# Apple Mach-o linke(Id) error undefined symbols for architecture i386 AppDelegate.o

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, linker-errors

Hi I have been having this problem for a very long time and its driving me insane.

```
Ld /Users/soc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/friendSpotted-dohwbjpnqfiztkcphlehsjqjusjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/friendSpotted.app/friendSpotted normal i386
    cd /Users/soc/Desktop/friendSpotted
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/soc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/friendSpotted-dohwbjpnqfiztkcphlehsjqjusjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/soc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/friendSpotted-dohwbjpnqfiztkcphlehsjqjusjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/soc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/friendSpotted-dohwbjpnqfiztkcphlehsjqjusjk/Build/Intermediates/friendSpotted.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/friendSpotted.build/Objects-normal/i386/friendSpotted.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000 -framework MobileCoreServices -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/soc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/friendSpotted-dohwbjpnqfiztkcphlehsjqjusjk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/friendSpotted.app/friendSpotted

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This has literally put me at a dead end, and I have tried some solutions on this site to no avail. I have checked the viewController.m to see if it was targeting the right project which it was, and as far as I can see I have all the right frameworks added. See below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o6SJ.jpg

Please I really do need help with this, I will greatly appreciate it.

Comment: seems you have not included some frameworks.

Comment: Looks like your viewcontroller.m file is actually declaring a cameraViewController class, not ViewController

Comment: Thanks Fred, that seemed to be the problem,I just changed the name back there to ViewController. Thanks again!